# Calibre. Link book's source code

Tags: calibre

All my programming books are stored in Calibre and many of them have source code with examples. Can I link book with source code examples for this book in Calibre?

**Specific example:**
I have this ebook in my library: [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/). Source code for this book is available for download: http://www.manning.com/seemann/DIi.NET_SourceCode.zip. What I want, is to have this source code to be linked with book so I could browse it from calibre i.e. by clicking link "Browse source code" or something similar.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Added explanation to my question.

Comment: Maybe...  I know you can create custom fields in Calibre, as well as extensions...  No reason why you couldnt do it.  The question is how much work.  Ill look when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You can add zip files to current book using `Add -> Add files to selected book record` menu item on the main toolbar with the book selected. Shortcut is `Shift+A`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a custom column.

Unfortunately, Calibre (still) doesn't have "hyperlink" data type.
So, there are 2 options:

- Generic "text" type. This text isn't interpreted as hyperlink, so you have to copy-paste the link to a browser. The value is shown in Book details as a hyperlink, but it points to a search filter inside Calibre
- Type "Long text", interpreted as Markdown. Inline hyperlinks are not interpreted, so to have a hyperlink you have to use explicit Markdown:

  ```markdown
  [Browse source code](http://www.manning.com/seemann/DIi.NET_SourceCode.zip)
  ```